# Best way to see if a string contains any elements in an array of substrings? And then replace if matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Alright so I have many URLs I need to decode (specifically, I need to decode encoded special characters such as "+", "|", etc.).

I have a list of the encoded characters I need to search for in the URL string. What is the best way I can take a string, look for any substring taken from a array of substrings in that string, and then replace that substring.

Example:

Say this is the list of substrings I'm looking for in the main string and what they need to be encoded/decoded to.

```
!   %21
"   %22
#   %23
$   %24
%   %25
&   %26
'   %27
(   %28
)   %29
*   %2A
+   %2B
,   %2C
-   %2D
```

And I have this as my string:

```
test.com/abc%2Bblahblah%28blahblah%22
```

How can I match my list of substrings to this main string so that the main string becomes:

```
test.com/abc+blahblah(blahblah"
```

Comment: Do you realize there is a [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) built in to decode this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly replace the string as in your example, use `decodeURIComponent`:

```
decodeURIComponent('test.com/abc%2Bblahblah%28blahblah%22')
// => test.com/abc+blahblah(blahblah"
```

Comment: unescape is deprecated

Comment: Oh wow how did I not know about this function. Yup this is exactly what I needed thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
decodeURIComponent('test.com/abc%2Bblahblah%28blahblah%22');
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have noted that `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()` can be used for the specific character encoding scheme in your example.

For the benefit of future generations who come to this question with different requirements, if you wanted a generic string-swapping scheme, something like this would work:

```
function encoderDecoder(legend) {
  this.encode = _encode;
  this.decode = _decode;
  function _encode(text) {
    for (var i = 0, len = legend.length; i < len; i++) {
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(legend[i].decoded, 'g'), legend[i].encoded);
    }
    return text;
  }
  function _decode(text) {
    var i = legend.length;
    while (i--) {
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(legend[i].encoded, 'g'), legend[i].decoded);
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

You could then create an encoder/decoder object by passing in an object representing your mappings/legend.

```
var mappings = [
    {decoded: "e", encoded: "3"}, 
    {decoded: "l", encoded: "1"}, 
    {decoded: "o",encoded: "0"}, 
    {decoded: "t",encoded: "7"},
    {decoded: "a",encoded: "4"}
    ];

var decoder = new encoderDecoder(mappings);
```

At this point you could invoke the `decoder.decode(str)` and `decoder.encode(str)` methods of the object, as in the example snippet below.

```js
function encoderDecoder(legend) {
  this.encode = _encode;
  this.decode = _decode;

  function _encode(text) {
    for (var i = 0, len = legend.length; i < len; i++) {
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(legend[i].decoded, 'g'), legend[i].encoded);
    }
    return text;
  }

  function _decode(text) {
    var i = legend.length;
    while (i--) {
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(legend[i].encoded, 'g'), legend[i].decoded);
    }
    return text;
  }
}

var mappings = [{
  decoded: "e",
  encoded: "3"
}, {
  decoded: "l",
  encoded: "1"
}, {
  decoded: "o",
  encoded: "0"
}, {
  decoded: "t",
  encoded: "7"
}, {
  decoded: "a",
  encoded: "4"
}];

var decoder = new encoderDecoder(mappings);
updateOutput();

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", updateOutput);

function updateOutput() {
  var value = document.querySelector("input").value;
  document.getElementById("encoded_output").innerHTML = decoder.encode(value);
  document.getElementById("decoded_output").innerHTML = decoder.decode(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello world" />
<br/>Encoded: <span id="encoded_output"></span>
<br/>Decoded: <span id="decoded_output"></span>
```

One caveat with this approach is that the regular expressions are processed against the entire string sequentially, so if one of the string swapping rules that comes later matches a string or substring that has been added by a preceding rule, it'll double-encode it. And contrariwise, some rules might never find a match if a preceding rule has modified the string in a way that precludes the rule from being met.

This problem only matters for certain types of encoding/decoding rules: those which allow overlap. So if, for example, you wanted to add a mapping of "cker" to "XXORZ" in my above example code, you'd find that "cker" gets transformed to "ck3r" with the first mapping ("e" to "3"), so the new rule would never be able to find a match.